# How to automate deployment in Kubernetes based eLearning System

Tags: docker, kubernetes, automation, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to develop a Kubernetes based eLearning system to teach students basic Linux commands and functions. I use Kubernetes to host the containers of an experiment. Each experiment was previously described by a Kubernetes manifest. Containers are accessed via WebSSH2.  In parallel I use Wordpress Blogging System to explain the experiment and the single steps to the student. 
My problem is that I haven't found a solution on how to trigger the deployment of a manifest on the Kubernetes cluster as soon as a user starts an experiment.

Does there exist any tools or patterns to automate this task?

Comment: I don't get what are you trying to do but I think is kind of this https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes. Anyway, if you want to deploy/update a deployment within the cluster, lohhed into a container, you can communicate with `kube-api` service using `kubectl` within the pod adding a proper `clusterRole` and `clusterRoleBind` to the pod.

Comment: I'm avoiding katacoda since we cannot afford to pay a fee if they one day decide to charge one. At the moment im using PHP shell_exec with kubectl to deploy my manifest. But this seems a bit wobbly

Comment: You might want to create an operator (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) and custom resources (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/). Also, you couls use GitOps principle where you van install some software like ArgoCD or flux on your k8s cluster, configure thise to look at a remot gir repo an commit/push changes/new deployent on it. ArgoCD or flux will sync your cluster with the git repo (https://github.com/fluxcd/flux)